# Problemas com ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, animação

Eu estou fazendo uma animação onde uma imagem desliza de baixo para cima usando ObjectAnimator. No emulador do Android Studio a animação ocorre de forma perfeita, mas quando eu rodo nos aparelhos com Android (testei em mais de dois), a animação parece dar um pulo.

Aqui está o código:

```
imgAnim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagem);
ob = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgAnim, "y", height, 70);
ob.setDuration(2100);
ob.start();
```

Comment: Reverti a edição para que tudo fique coerente(a minha resposta ficaria sem sentido)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O pulo é devido ao valor da variável `height` não ser o valor da posição *y* onde se encontra a ImageView.

Ao iniciar a animação a imagem "salta" da sua posição para a posição `height` e só depois é iniciado o movimento suave entre `height` e `70`.

Para não haver salto, `height` tem de ter o valor da posição *y* da ImageView:

```
height = imgAnim.getY();
```

**Nota:**

O método `getY()` irá retornar `0` se for usado no `onCreate()`, nessa altura as views ainda não fora dimensionadas nem posicionadas.

Se o código que postou **não estiver** no `onCreate()` nem estiver a ser chamado dele altere a linha

```
ob = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgAnim, "y", height, 70);
```

para

```
ob = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgAnim, "y", imgAnim.getY(), 70);
```

Se estiver, tem de garantir que seja executado após as views terem sido dimensionadas e posicionadas.

Para isso crie um método para colocar o código da animação:

```
private void animateImage(ImageView imageView, float startY, float endY){

    ObjectAnimator ob = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "y", startY, endY);
    ob.setDuration(2100);
    ob.start();
}
```

No método `onCreate()`, adicione um OnGlobalLayoutListener à ImageView e chame o método `animateImage()` no método `onGlobalLayout()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ....
    ....
    imgAnim = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagem);
    imgAnim.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 

        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                //Remove o listenner para não ser novamente chamado.
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    imgAnim.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    //noinspection deprecation
                    imgAnim.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }

                //Aqui a ImageView já foi dimensionada e posicionada
                //inicia a animação
                animateImage(imgAnim, imgAnim.getY(), 70);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Olha, no emulador funciona direitinho, mas no celular continua com um delay inicial.

Comment: Se você está a usar o código da resposta não encontro razão. No entanto sem ver o que você chama de delay fica difícil saber o porquê. Vou tentar testar num celular para ver se reproduzo esse comportamento.

Comment: Quando a imagem vai começar a se deslocar, ela vai de um ponto até outro sem deslizar e só depois é que ela começa a deslizar até a posição final.

Comment: Tem a certeza que tem o código tal e qual como está na resposta?

Comment: Coloquei meu código atual na pergunta.

Comment: Não vejo nada de errado. Coloque, na pergunta, o xml da Activity